# Problem encoding multibyte characters with Perl's HTML::Entities

Tags: html, perl, html-entities

```
$perl -e 'use HTML::Entities; print encode_entities("<te£st>");'
&lt;te&Acirc;&pound;st&gt;
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
&lt;te&pound;st&gt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use utf8;
```

(put that at the top of the script).

Comment: Add something like "That informs the perl interpreter that your source code contains literal utf8."